# ImportError: cannot import name migrations in python-social-auth

Tags: django, django-south, python-social-auth, django-migrations

I am using django==1.6. I installed python-social-auth for social authentication. But when I am trying to migrate the Database i am getting this error.

```
    from django.db import models, migrations
    ImportError: cannot import name migrations
```

I tried to installed the older version of python-social-auth but still this error exists.
what should I do to solve this problem.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-social-auth` tries to use Django's built in migrations by default. These only work on Django versions >= 1.7. If you are using an older version of Django, and using South, there is still support for that. You need to add this to your settings:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'default': 'social.apps.django_app.default.south_migrations',
}
```

Source: [Github Issue #456](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/456)

Comment: I downgraded the version to 0.1.9 and it works for me . Thanks for your answer :)